# guzzle post requests returns malformed error

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I try to run passport '/oauth/clients' method to create new passport's client with guzzle and got

```
local.ERROR: cURL error 3: <url> malformed error
```

I do :

```
            $app_root_url = config('app.url');
            \Log::info('-1 REGISTER $app_root_url::');
            \Log::info($app_root_url);
            $headers =  [
                'content-type' => 'application/json',
                'verify' => true,
            ];

            $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $url = '/oauth/clients';

            $requestBody['name'] = $newUser->name;
            $requestBody['redirect'] = $app_root_url . '/callback';
//            $requestBody['Accept'] = 'application/json';  // Do I need this parameter ?

            \Log::info('-2 REGISTER $requestBody::');
            \Log::info($requestBody);

            $request = $guzzleClient->post( $url,  [
                "headers" => $headers,             // Do I need these params ?
                'form_params' => $requestBody      // ERROR REFERING THIS LINE
            ]);
            $response = $request->send();
            \Log::info('-3 REGISTER $response::');
            \Log::info($response);
```

I log file I see :

```
local.INFO: -1 REGISTER $app_root_url::  
local.INFO: http://local-hostels3-backend-api.com  
local.INFO: -2 REGISTER $requestBody::  
local.INFO: array (
  'name' => 'admin',
  'redirect' => 'http://local-hostels3-backend-api.com/callback',
)  
 local.ERROR: cURL error 3: <url> malformed (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) {"exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException(code: 0): cURL error 3: <url> malformed (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:201)
[stacktrace]
#0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(155): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(105): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory))
#2 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory))
#3 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#4 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(51): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#5 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(66): GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#6 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(29): GuzzleHttp\\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#7 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RedirectMiddleware.php(70): GuzzleHttp\\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#8 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(59): GuzzleHttp\\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#9 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php(71): GuzzleHttp\\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#10 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(361): GuzzleHttp\\HandlerStack->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#11 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(163): GuzzleHttp\\Client->transfer(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Array)
#12 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(183): GuzzleHttp\\Client->requestAsync('post', Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Uri), Array)
#13 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(96): GuzzleHttp\\Client->request('post', '/oauth/clients', Array)
#14 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels3-backend-api/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php(207): GuzzleHttp\\Client->__call('post', Array)
#15 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthController->register(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
```

In my app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php I added passport routes definition :

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();
}
```

...

```
 "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
 "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
 "laravel/passport": "^8.1",
```

What raized this error and how to fix it ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK:**
I added parameter to my headers :

```
$headers =  [
    'content-type' => 'application/json',
    'verify' => true,
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrf_token()
];
```

But debugging this array I see it containes :

```
array (
  'content-type' => 'application/json',
  'verify' => true,
  0 => 'X-CSRF-TOKEN',
  1 => NULL,
)
```

That is backend rest api app and I do not any form with csrf hidden in it.
Have I to init csrf in someway?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `$url` variable is only having path sections missing any host it must target.

Prepend the variable with the route host and thus providing full URL value for the Guzzle client.

Probable solution:

```php
$url = config('app.url') . '/oauth/clients';
```

**EDIT**
You can also set your `app URL` as the base URL for Guzzle client.

Comment: Looks like you are right, I set full url , but next I got "resulted in a `419 unknown status` response" error. Usually this error is raised with csrf missed, but which csrf token have I to provide in guzzle client post request ?

Comment: for any post and put requests to be accepted by Laravel application, either you have to unset `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware from the route you are requesting or must set `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header for your request.

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: `'X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrf_token()`

1. the comma must be replaced with `=>`
2. ensure `csrf_token()` is providing you the valid CSRF token to submit

Comment: 1) Yes, I have misspelling with “=>”, but csrf_token() returnes null
In routes/api.php controls route route is defined :
Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register')->name('api.register');

2) I can comment VerifyCsrfToken middleware in kernel, but if that is safe. That would be backend rest api app with 
passport as auth driver.

Comment: If its an API route, you are not required to submit X-CSRF-TOKEN header but need other token based headers as you setup during passport installation. Unless you are adding `web` middleware with your routes, csrf won't be a problem for default configured Laravel.

For your case, you can debug if request is reaching your targeted location and for any other causes that might be causing Guzzle to fail.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure which steps have I to take to salve the problem?

Comment: You can place a request logger on your end-point, debug through the request there and find the cause for failed execution. You can try removing any forms of authentication required for the route to allow full access and then gradually restrict the access with your passport implementation. You can also log the response from Guzzle request and analyze it for issues.